# Shell Scripting: Quotes Around Variable with \$

Tags: linux, shell

I've just started learning about shell scripting and have been trying to workout what's going on in this script: http://dev.cloudtrax.com/wiki/ng-cs-ip-logging

Specifically, I can't wrap my head around a couple of lines that use `"\$foo"` for example:

`[ -z "\$plug_event" ] && return`

Everything I've read and learned about shell scripting has me believing that `"\$plug_event"` would evaluate as a string whose value is `$plug_event`. This would mean that the above test would *always* return a `1` (i.e. the test was false), right? If so, what's the point?

I've found plenty on quotes around variables but so far I haven't been able to find a single example of this kind of usage. Is it just a typo? Unfortunately I'm nowhere near experienced enough to tell the difference yet.

All help is much appreciated, and a link to a relevant document would certainly suffice.

Cheers,
Kyle

Comment: Is your specific question with regards to the "\"?  If so, it looks like he is just escaping the variable so that it's not interpreted by the shell.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. If that's the case, what's the point of the test?

Comment: I think it's a pointless test unless that variable is expanded in another shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for escaping all the `$`s is that those lines are part of [here-docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

The command `cat > /etc/ip_logging.sh << EOF` will output all of following text into `/etc/ip_logging.sh` until it hits `EOF`, and not to evaluate the variables in the current script, the `$` has to be escaped.

Alternatively, and to make the code easier to read, putting the terminating string in single quotes will disable variable substitution in the heredoc:

```
cat > /etc/ip_logging.sh << 'EOF'
    [ -z "$plug_event" ]
    #other stuff
EOF
```

will have same result, sans the escaped `$` and other shell special characters

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying. The backslash is only being used in this case because they're using `cat` to write the file?

Comment: @KyleG. correct, edited my answer with a way to avoid using backslashes

Comment: Wow, I've been busting my head on this for close to an hour. Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

The test:

```
[ -z "\$plug_event" ]
```

is pointless.  The string is never zero length; the return after it is never executed.

Whoever wrote that code did not understand what they were doing ... unless there are extenuating circumstances such as it is part of a here-doc which is then treated specially.

But, standing on its own, the statement is pointless.

...look at the code...

```
# create iptables script on the fly
cat > /etc/ip_logging.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/functions.sh

install_rule() {
        config_get plug_event "\$1" plug_event

        [ -z "\$plug_event" ] && return

        pub_ip=\$(uci get dhcp.pub.ipaddr)
        pub_mask=\$(uci get dhcp.pub.netmask)

        priv_ip=\$(uci get dhcp.priv.ipaddr)
        priv_mask=\$(uci get dhcp.priv.netmask)

        iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o br-\$1 -s \$pub_ip/\$pub_mask -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix "iplog: "
        iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o br-\$1 -s \$priv_ip/\$priv_mask -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix "iplog: "
}

config_load network
config_foreach install_rule interface
EOF
```

Someone did know more or less what they are up to; they are writing a script in a here-doc and need the parameters expanded when the script that's being generated is executed, not when it is created.  They could have simplified life by using:

```
# create iptables script on the fly
cat > /etc/ip_logging.sh << 'EOF'
```

The quotes around the end marker mean that no expansions are done in the here-doc, so all the backslashes could go.

The `bash` [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is your friend.  [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is one relevant section, but it covers actual expansions, not suppressed expansions.